# Fetching one row only with MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli

How can I only fetch one INDEXED row with MySQLi? I'm currently doing this:

```
$row = $result->fetch(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$row = $row[0];
```

Is there another way?

I'm aware of mysqli_fetch_row but it doesn't return an associative array.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Use `$row = $result->fetch_assoc();` - it's the same as `fetch_row()` but returns an associative array.

Comment: Also, see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php fetch_assoc manual page.