# PHP Trouble Getting Data From Mysqli Table

Tags: php, mysql

Before ANYONE judges... I have check other posts that have similar issues but still no luck solving my problem.

[php mysqli only returns one row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664659/php-mysqli-only-returns-one-row)

[Fetching one row only with MySQLi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893572/fetching-one-row-only-with-mysqli)

I have also checked and read the PHP manual, no luck using different methodologies to extract the data.
I mean I do extract a table, the table even has the correct number of rows. HOWEVER, ALL the rows have the same information: the first row, the one that indicates the headers ie: FirstName, Phone, Address, etc.

The code below shows just a bit how I am doing it. I reiterate, the mysqli connection is indeed extracting a table with data, with the correct row count. But I am not getting the correct info.

```
public function queryexec()
{   
  if(isset($this->query))
  {
    //execute prepared query and store in result variable.
    $this->result = $this->connection->query($this->query);
    echo 'Table Row Count: '. $this->result->num_rows;

        echo '<br/>';

        //fetch_array gives me table but only headers but correct amount of rows.
        //Fetch_object doesnt work throws me error: 
        //Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array   
        while($row = $this->result->fetch_array()){

             printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row[2][1]);
            //echo 'Table Data: '. $newdata["LastName"];
           //echo '<br/>';
        }

        return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: try using `while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM, PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT)) {`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: I suppose the $stmt is the result from the query right?

But it gave me an error:  Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch()

Comment: Yeah, in your case you'd use `$this->fetch_object` or `$this->fetch_assoc` : http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: It didn't work though, so my best bet will be to try PDO api for this task.

Comment: Tried $this->result->fetch_object also? Good luck :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling fetch_object() but then you're accessing row elements as if it's an ordinal array.

You should either access a column like a field of an object `$row->LastName` or else change the way you fetch a row to use `$this->result->fetch_array()`.

---

I just tested your code, using PHP 5.3.26, and MySQL 5.6.13.  I got no errors, and I got distinct data for all three rows:

```
mysql> show create table test.foo\G

CREATE TABLE `foo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `z` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LastName` text,
  `t` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

mysql> insert into foo (id, lastname) values 
(1, 'Granger'), (2, 'Potter'), (3, 'Weasley');

$ php 19236839.php
Table Row Count: 3<br/>
1 (r)
2 (o)
3 (e)
```

Note that `$row[2][1]` returns a single character, the second character in the string.

Comment: I am using indeed $this->result->fectch_array(), but I am still having the same issue.

Comment: Look above I added some more info about the error.
With fetch_array I am not getting error. But my table that has 3 rows ALL data inside them have the same data which is the name of the field.

Comment: Yeah I do know about $row[0][1], though I did it to make sure I was not going crazy, but the info I need should be in $row['FirstName'];

I even changed the DB connection with PDO api since many said it is better..

I still get same results -_-. I need to solve this today and I can't win with this db problem. I know its my fault but I dont know where

Comment: PHP ver.5.3.13 and mySQL ver.5.5